# Simple React tutorial for displaying a Json data response based on a HTTP Request through a button?

Tags: reactjs, json, spring, spring-boot, frontend

I have a Spring Boot backend that outputs certain Json data upon certain GET or POST requests.

Is there a simple tutorial for creating a react .js/.css combination to create a request through a button, interpret the Json response and display it?

*(Right now I have to manually enter the HTTP GET request and I get a raw Json String response, that's where I'm at...)*

My Front-end knowledge has been slowly going down to near zero over the last years... And for some reason I can't seem to find an easy example.

I have tried some Google / Youtube searches but the results that I get are using a Json file inside the React project for instance, that's not what I'm looking for :D

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-consume-rest-apis-in-react/
hope it helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example of a basic component that uses https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/ to fetch and display some todo items when clicking on a button.

The component needs 2 states. The first one is used to follow if the button was pressed or not. Initially, the button is not pressed, so the "Get Todo List" button is rendered. When we press it, the state is updated and the `getTodos` function is called. Since this function makes a request, it is an async function, which uses the fetch API to call the JsonPlaceholder endpoint, and updates the second state with the response data. The `.json()` method needs to be called to parse the data in a JSON format.

After pressing the button, the value of `isDataFetched` is updated, and a re-rendering is triggered. This is why the button is not displayed anymore, and since the `isDataFetched` is still empty, the "Loaging..." paragraph will be showed. After the request is finished and the `todos` value is updated, another re-rendering is triggered, and this time, the list with the todo items will be displayed.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

export default function App() {
  const [isDataFetched, setIsDataFetched] = useState(false);
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

  async function getTodos() {
    try {
      const res = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/`);
      const todos = await res.json();
      setTodos(todos);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }

  function handleClick() {
    setIsDataFetched(!isDataFetched);
    getTodos();
  }

  if (!isDataFetched) {
    return <button onClick={handleClick}>Get Todo List</button>;
  }

  if (todos.length === 0) {
    return <p>Loading...</p>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {todos.map((todoItem, index) => (
          <li key={index}>{todoItem.title}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I hope it helps you a little bit!